# Can virtual types be used as source models for EAV attributes?

Tags: magento2, eav, virtualtype

I'm creating my own EAV entity and one of the attributes of my entity has the type `select` so it requires a source model.
But I don't want to create my own class just for this attribute since I already have a virtual type defined for it that I use in the form and grid for a flat entity in the same module.

```
<virtualType name="SomeTypeNameHere" type="[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\Source\Options">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label 1</item>
            </item>
            <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label 2</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Can I use `SomeTypeNameHere` as a `source_model` for an attribute ?
I know I can test this, but I'm far from having a functional entity. I'm still in the setup phase (more or less).
If someone already tried this I could use a simple Yes/No answer so I know which direction to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

95% sure that it works.

If the Source Model is instantiated by the ObjectManager (I really think, or at least hope so, the Object Manager just creates a new Object of `[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\Source\Options` with the parameters defined for `SomeTypeNameHere`

Comment: Thanks for this. I will take this approach, with virtual types as source models, and if it does not work it's your fault :D.

Comment: all clear, I'm also curious ;)